# Are Guinea pigs related to the sea?

Tags: etymology

> Das Meerschweinchen -> The Guinea pig

If we can think of the word as Meer-Schweinchen, Meer means sea and Schweinchen means piglet. Is there any historical reason for Guinea Pig's to be called Ocean piglets?

Comment: Note that the figurative Guinea pig is to be translated as *Versuchskaninchen* instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the guinea pig has been imported from overseas. It is called pig, "because it makes the sound of a pig". See the "Etymologie" section at: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Meerschweinchen

Another instance of a German word, where *Meer-* is indicating exotic provenance is *Meerkatze* ("guenon"), as they stem from Africa. For *Meerrettich* ("horse raddish"), there is a theory, that the naming follows the same pattern (see [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Meerrettich#/Meerrettich) for more details).

Comment: Another word where *Meer* can be interpreted as "from overseas" or "exotic" is *Meerrettich* = "horse radish".

Comment: @RDBury Nice. I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another theory for "Meerkatze" is that is derived from the Sanskrit word "markata“ (which means monkey). See https://www.biologie-seite.de/Biologie/Meerkatzen. For "Meerschweinchen" also see https://www.meerschweinchen-wissen.de/allgemein/der-name-meerschweinchen-erklaerung/.

Comment: @PaulFrost Interesting. Unfortunately, the second theory has no source in the linked article. Do you have a linguistic source for the theory? The etymological dictionary at dwds (Wolfgang Pfeifer: Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen) only mentions the overseas theory.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach You are right, there is no source for the "markata" theory. But I also doubt that there is a reliable source for the overseas theory. In my opinion each explanation is somewhat speculative; it only appears to be more or less plausible.

Comment: This is patent Ammen-Märchen, as there is no such naming scheme where Meer-, See- etc. would indicate exotic origin instead of ex-oceanis. The further examples to that effect have already been called into question. Next we'll probably hear about Aphrodite and Merkur. A more likely origin would be words for small size (surprisingly, I know) eg. Slovene majhen, Icelandic  smár, some like that.